# Making a Gradient Follow a Loop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I recently started learning Adobe Illistrator and I'm trying to make a gradient follow a loop. From what I could find online, I've learned how to make a gradient follow a path, but I can't find anything that involves a path that overlaps in a loop. What I have in mind is something like this, where the gradient follows the red arrows and continues to follow the path as it goes behind the base of the loop.
[image: This is just to illistrate what I have in mind, it's not the result of any of my attempts]
I tried making a path using the Line Segment and Arc Tools, and then joining them (in the order that I want the path to go, not all the segments at once), but the resulting gradient didn't run smoothly along the loop. Then, I tried using the Pen Tool to make the loop and connecting it to line legments at the beginning and end of the loop, but that didn't yield a result either.

As I am rather new to Illistrator, I'm not quite sure what else to try. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single path with a **stroke**, using the `Apply Gradient Along Stroke` in the **Gradient Panel** should work.

[image]

---

If it's *not* a stroke, and is a *shape with a fill* then matters are more difficult. Generally, a **Gradient Mesh** would work best. But it's complicated. Meshes can become unruly and hard to edit/apply to an existing, non-rudimentary, shape. In fact, for a filled shape such as your loop, it can often be easier to *start* with a gradient on a *stroke*, then use `Expand Appearance` which will result in *shape* with a gradient mesh fill.....

[image]

... otherwise I'd create a long thin strip, apply a Gradient Mesh, then distort the strip into the loop, which is by no means an easy thing to do well, even for experienced Illustrator users.